# Asp.net profile in a separate assembly

Tags: asp.net, membership, profile

I have a web application which uses membership and profiles.  I successfully used the WebProfileBuilder extension, so my profile class is correctly generated, and is working nicely.

However, after a new request of my client, I need now to move that profile management part into another assembly (so I'd be able to get profile information in a windows service running on the same machine).

What I made is created the new assembly, moved my generated profile file, and tried to use it from the other assembly, but without any success.  I always get a `SettingsPropertyNotFoundException`.  My thought is that the profile system doesn't know where to find its connection information, so I tried to add the connectionstring and provider in the app.config of this assembly, but this doesn't seem to work.

What am I missing ?  Is it possible to do ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found what's wrong... Thanks to this blog post:

http://fredrik.nsquared2.com/viewpost.aspx?postid=244&showfeedback=true

The only thing I needed to do is add `applicationName="/"` in my provider configuration, in the app.config. (which is the application name, can be found inside the aspnet_Applications table in the DB.

```
<configuration>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add
        name="MyConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=...;Initial Catalog=...;User ID=...;Password=..."
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <profile
      enabled="true"
      defaultProvider="Sql2008ProfileProvider">
      <properties>
        <add name="UserLevel" type="integer"/>
        <add name="value1" type="string" />
        <add name="value2" type="string"  />
        <add name="value3" type="string" />
        <add name="value4" type="string"/>
      </properties>

      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add
            name="Sql2008ProfileProvider"
            type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider"
            connectionStringName="MyConnectionString"
            applicationName="/"
            />
      </providers>

    </profile>
  </system.web>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got a nasty suspicion that your APP.Config file won't be picked by the web application;  did you keep the settings in your Web.Config file ?

I've only found app.config to work on such an assemply when using NUnit or similar.

Comment: I removed what was between `<profile>...</profile>` from my web.config, and the problem is still there.

Comment: Oh sorry, I mean to say you should try and keep the stuff in web.config and *not* move it to the app.config.

I had exactly the same problem trying to consume some WCF services. The designer insisted on putting the bindings in app.config, but then threw the exception when I tried to load the page. I had to move the settings into Web.Config then it all started working.

Comment: This was my initial try, and it doesn't work either :-(

Now... Given that my windows service is using the new assembly, where should I place the app.config ?  In the assembly or in the windows service ?

Comment: Just made another try, disabling the profileBuilder, removing the generated files from the web app, so I'm sure it only uses the profile part of the new assembly.  I also removed the config section in the *web.config*, and got the same error.  Will made other tries, and keep you updated...

Comment: Ok I'm kind of lost now...  I retried the same setting as just before, but with the profile settings present in the *web.config*... And the website part works now!  Now I still have to understand why it doesn't work with the new assembly...